Table inaccessible after old s3 files are deep archived in Glacier for Hive table
My table is inaccessible after old s3 files are deep archived in Glacier for Hive table.
Exception:  java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=94761, contentLength=111145

The Hive table is bucketed on employee_id and the orc files pointing to it in External bucket have been deep archived.
How can we re-access the table without bringing the old archived data back to standard?
I understand, for partitioned table, we drop the archived partition from Hive metastore using alter command, but how to handle in case of Bucket table.
Hive version: 2.3.9-amzn-2
